# Where to find a more comprehensive tutorial on writing plugins for maven-checkstyle-plugin

Tags: maven-2, hudson, checkstyle

I am looking for a tutorial on how to extend http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/ (run within [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)), in particular, I am looking for information if I can create -- for my customize checkstyle check -- an additionally html page with details of an error message in the generated project website. I would like to have a page on the error details with a large graph with highlighted incorrect nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the [Hudson checkstyle plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Checkstyle+Plugin).

There is an tutorial available for [plugin development for Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugin+tutorial).

Last but not least, have a look at a question regarding [plugin development for Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308865/good-tutorial-for-writing-maven-plugins).

Answer (score 0):

take a look at our project, we also extends Checkstyle to use in maven plugin - https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle (see project sevntu-checkstyle-maven-plugin)